# Windows PostgreSQL logs indicate many short time sessions

Tags: .net, database, postgresql, odbc

I'm using windows XP with PostgreSQL 9.2.3, ODBC driver 9.01.0100, during some stress testing recently with *log_connections* and *log_disconnections* **on**, I noticed there're too many this kind of logs in log file:

```
2014-02-26 10:37:14.359 ,"connection received: host=127.0.0.1 port=11978",,,,,,,,,""
2014-02-26 10:37:14.359 ,"myUser","mydatabase",7996,"127.0.0.1:11978","authentication","connection authorized: user=myUser database=mydatabase",,,,,,,,,""

2014-02-26 10:37:14.390 ,"myUser","mydatabase","127.0.0.1:11978","disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.031 user=myUser database=mydatabase host=127.0.0.1 port=11978",,,,,,,,,""
```

Noticed the session time is very small which far from 1 seconds: **'session time: 0:00:00.031'**, and obviously it did nothing in this session but Open and close.

As I know, our business is based on .NET which of course use the ADO.NET, there's a connection pool facility default enabled, this is for saving the physical link to database every time we open a connection in code, so I really confuse what this log mean? does this hurt the performance lot?

Comment: Looks like the ADO.NET connection pool probably isn't being used. As for what it did, unless `log_statement = 'all'` is enabled, you don't know whether it did something in between connect and disconnect.

Comment: Do you have any kind of NMS? We are using opennms, and it periodically makes connections similar to this in order to probe that the service is up and running.

Comment: Is there any fixed interval to these connections?

Comment: I Don't think the ADO.NET connection pool was disabled and as I know, seems there's no way to disable it?        After i enable the log_statment all, I do see some query from our application, I'm on the way to investigate that, but still wonder why the connection pool seems lost its function?